# How to convert a dict into a pandas multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

I´m handling distances between elements (e.g. a1,a2, ...) of different attributes (e.g. A, B, ...) and I choose a `dict` to store the distances. The `dict` has the following form:

```
mydict = {('A', ('a1','a2')): 1.0,
          ('A', ('a1','a3')): 0.5,
          ('A', ('a2','a1')): 1.1,
          ('A', ('a2','a3')): 0.8,
          ('A', ('a3','a1')): 1.2,
          ('A', ('a3','a2')): 1.2,
          ('B', ('b1','b2')): 1.0,
          ('B', ('b1','b3')): 0.5,
          ('B', ('b2','b1')): 1.1,
          ('B', ('b2','b3')): 0.8,
          ('B', ('b3','b1')): 1.2,
          ('B', ('b3','b2')): 1.2,
          }
```

So the keys of the `dict` are `tuple`s with a first element giving the attribute and the second element beeing a `tuple` itself giving the two elements, which distance is given in the corresponding value.

Now I want to display the data in form of crosstables which should look somewhat like this:

```
A   a1   a2   a3
a1    0  1.0   0.5
a2  1.1    0   0.8
a3  1.2  1.2    0

B   b1   b2   b3
b1    0  1.0   0.5
b2  1.1    0   0.8
b3  1.2  1.2    0
```

and so on for each attribut.

I tried to to convert the data to a `DataFrame` in oder to maybe use the `casstab` function of pandas. I tried to convert the keys of the dict to a list and use `pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples` and then `MultiIndex.to_frame` but I did´t get a usable format.

Any suggestions how to deal with this or to store the distance data differently to begin with?

Comment: kindly provide reproducible sample of the dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the format of the data is fine. You just need to unpack it correctly to get a useable dataframe.

- Construct a dataframe from the dict values and dict keys.
- Unpack the level of the index with the element names to two columns.
- Apply crosstab with the appropriate index and columns (apply `.fillna(0)` to the result to get the exact same structure as in your question).

`df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict.values(), pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(my_dict.keys()))
df[['first_element', 'second_element']] = df.index.get_level_values(1).to_list()
pd.crosstab(
            [df.index.get_level_values(0), df.first_element],
            df.second_element,
            values=df[0],
            aggfunc='sum'
            )`

Comment: thx for your quick response. 
In case of multiple attributes your code produces one big crosstab which is quite sparse (which could also be a desireable output, of course). 
For my use case I was able to use your code snippets and create a function which returns the crosstab for any given attribute. So thanks again!

Comment: Hey, you're welcome. You can access individual attributes, like 'A',  in the big crosstab by applying ```.loc['A']```